# having issues with install bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the compiler error I get when trying to bundle install.

```
Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
An error occurred while installing rack (2.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I `ruby -v` I get `-v ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]`
and also doing `gem install rack -v '2.2.3'` works but it still gives me the same error when try to bundle install.

Comment: what is the output of `bundle show rack`

Comment: '[DEPRECATED] use `bundle info rack` instead of `bundle show rack`
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.1.3) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile.' when I do bundle info rack I get Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.1.3) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: Are you using RVM or another Ruby version manager? Can you show us your Gemfile and your `gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 0):

You have several versions of Rack. You have to uninstall all versions except `2.2.3`
So, do this:

```
bundle info rack

# then check all versions and run this code for each versions except 2.2.3 
# replace __VERSION__ with unneeded rack version
gem uninstall rack -v '__VERSION__'
```

Cheers